# what voltage required to replace schottky diode to zener diode

Tags: power-electronics

I have very basic question. what value of zener voltage I need to replace schottky diode with Vrrm=40V?

Comment: A Zener diode and a Schottky diode are for different things. Why do you want to replace one with the other?

Comment: Exactly. You'll need to give some background on what you use the Schottky diode with. Also, a single number, in this case Vrrm, doesn't specify your diode at all. So, please add a schematic (use the schematic editor in the "edit" box) and explain what the Diode is used for. But: it's very likely you *can't* replace one with the other. They're really different devices, meant for different purposes, typically.

Comment: BAS40-04-7 this is dual schottky diode which I am using and I need to replace this with zener diode

Comment: *Why* do you need to replace it with a *zener* diode? Just repeating your statement won't make it make more sense. You need to provide context.

Comment: it is just used for reverse  protection.

Comment: I need to read the analog input supplied to motor terminal in controller.for that purpose I am using voltage divider to reduce higher voltage pulse coming in case of fault.ther I am using schottky diode in parallel with divider

Comment: Bla bla bla, draw a schematic so that is is clear what you're doing. You still have not explaind **WHY** you want to replace the Schottky with a Zener. You mention "motor" which hints at reasons why you should **not** use a zener diode.

Answer (score 2):

Zener diodes are silicon junctions, which have a forward voltage around 0.7v, and a stable non-destructive reverse breakdown (as long as you stick to dissipation limits) at their specified zener voltage. They are only really used for their reverse characteristic, the forward characteristic is essentially a by-product of their construction.

Schottky diodes are hetero-contacts, with a forward voltage around 0.4v, a high (with respect to silicon) reverse leakage, that increases strongly with temperature and can cause a surprising thermal runaway in some diodes if not heat-sinked properly, and a destructive reverse breakdown when the reverse voltage exceeds some poorly specified threshold.

They have different applications. If you want to do a lateral thinking exercise, then the only time they might be considered interchangeable is when used as rectifiers, when the maximum reverse voltage is below the zener voltage, and within the reverse spec of the schottky. But that would be a very strange way to use a zener!